# Headlines broken in org themes

Tags: org-mode, themes

Here is an example .org file displayed with the solarized-dark theme:

[image]

Now here's what happens when I switch the theme to leuven:

[image]

Similar things happen in some other themes (like wombat). Looking at other files, it appears that the fifth headline is printed, but it's way off to the right and takes up the entire screen.

My `.spacemacs` file contains no modifications apart from a few key bindings. Has anyone seen this problem before?

Comment: Are you restarting emacs? I think themes don't load correctly when they are changed with SPC T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by my changing the default font to Terminess Powerline. The usual default of Source Code Pro displays org-mode correctly.